Black Screen temporarily fixed by plugging/unplugging external monitor. How to permanently fix?
My laptop has been suffering black screens within a few minutes of boot up. That is, the screen goes black but I know the computer is still running and nothing has crashed. I managed to find a workaround: Attach an external monitor and set the display to use only the external monitor and not the laptop's own screen. See the details here: How to Change Screen Display Settings When Primary Screen Has Failed
After that, I got lazy and simply got used to always using my external monitor and ignoring the laptop screen. But I've got a trip coming up where I obviously can't bring the external monitor, so I'd like to fix the underlying issue: How to stop the black screens in the first place.
One new piece of information: Even long after the black screen has started, plugging in an external monitor and then unplugging apparently causes the laptop monitor to work again for a few minutes. So I don't think it's a matter of hardware being broken; it must be a software issue. It's not the power/sleep settings; I checked that.
What should I try next to diagnose/fix the black screens?
Thanks
A little more information: The laptop is a HP Notebook, Windows 10 Home.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Check the Event Viewer for power-related messages, but are you sure it is a software issue? Then your process is to update all drivers and firmware and the OS, and if the issue persists, do repair install of the OS. If that fails, you can attempt a full reinstall, or you can pursue hardware fixes.
